# Impact on Dashboards in Einstein Analytics on Org Instance Migration

Tags: einstein-analytics, migration, org, instance

We have created a set of dashboards, dataflows, datasets in the Einstein analytics in our current org. What all impacts do we have on the Einstein analytics on org instance migration or instance refresh? What all precautions or steps to be done before the migration ?

Answer (score 0):

These will likely all be lost.

1. Best would be to back everything up.

   - Dataflows
   - Dashboards
   - XMD
   - Security Predicates

This way you can load them all back up. And just run your dataflow and paste your dashboards back in. And they should all work normally.

2. A friend of ours has built the following package that could help hasten the process if you have many built. Then they will be backed up you reinstall the package and load the data back in.

If don't have any experience with the code or the analytics markup lingo, I would highly recommend this option.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFpHGUA1

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with this product?

Comment: No, I run a consultancy, riverBI, this is a product built by analyticscc

Technically we are competitors.

Comment: Ok. Please **[edit]** your post to include the name of the package you recommend and also clearly indicate you are not affiliated. Thanks!